# scp with a vertical line in directory

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, scp

Suppose I want to `scp` from cluster to local;

```
scp id@nodename:"~/Main/56|75/test.pdf" .
```

Here, the `|` is screwing up the `scp` transfer. If I move `test.pdf` into `/Main` then it'll function.

How do I call `scp` in a way that works with a `|` in the directory?

Comment: `scp` seems pass a remote file name to a shell on the remote end, so you need to be careful about how it is quoted. Local quoting, as you provide, is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape!

```
scp id@nodename:"~/Main/56\|75/test.pdf" .
```